# Javascript function for handling multiple unknown callbacks

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, callback

I have a scenario where I would like to send in 2 or more functions (as parameters) into a handler function, and have that handler function execute each passed function as a callback function for the preceding function.

Here is a general concept of the function I am trying to write:

```
function functionChain() {
   // MAKE SURE WE HAVE AT LEAST 1 PARAMETER
   if ( arguments.length < 1 ) { return; }

   // for each parameter, call it (as a function)
   for ( var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
     if ( typeof arguments[i] === 'function' ) {    
       call arguments[i];
     }
   }
}
// example
functionChain( function1, function2, function3 );
```

... so in the code above, each function will be called in succession.

Where I am getting stuck is how to treat each call as a callback when the previous function completes.

The way I would approach this is to have a variable (for simplicity, lets just say a global variable named functionChainComplete), and wait to launch the next function -- and of course, each function I call would set functionChainComplete to true. So, something like this:

```
// set global var for tracking
var functionChainComplete;

function functionChain() {
   // MAKE SURE WE HAVE AT LEAST 1 PARAMETER
   if ( arguments.length < 1 ) { return; }

   // SET GLOBAL VAR TO FALSE
   functionChainComplete = true;

   // for each parameter, call it (as a function)
   for ( var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
     if ( typeof arguments[i] === 'function' ) {    
       if ( functionChainComplete == true ) {
         // call the next function and wait for true again
         functionChainComplete = false;
         call arguments[i];
       } else {
         // try again in 50 ms (maybe setTimeout)?
       }
     }
   }
}

function1() { 
    // do something, and when done, reset functionChainComplete
    functionChainComplete = true;
}

function2() { 
    // do something, and when done, reset functionChainComplete
    functionChainComplete = true;
}

function3() { 
    // do something, and when done, reset functionChainComplete
    functionChainComplete = true;
}

// example
functionChain( function1, function2, function3 );
```

As you can see, the code above does not address the callback piece, and I am not sure where to take it from here - I suspect some sort of recursive function? I am stuck.

Comment: Do you care about the execution order of the functions when an event triggers?  What if some are async?  Perhaps a use case would explain what you need vs what you are asking for :)

Comment: *"...have that handler function execute each passed function as a callback function for the preceding function..."* It's not entirely clear what you mean by that. So if I do `functionChain(a, b, c, d)`, you want (in effect) `a(function() { b(function() { c(function() { d(); } } })`? What about arguments, should they be passed on?

Comment: order is paramount, and no need to pass params, although that would be useful (but I was thinking that was just another headache to solve later). thanks. In example, function 1 should run and complete, then function2, then 3. each function runs async, which is why i need this functionChain in the first place -- trying to solve a scenario that occurs in my app a lot - a series of functions that need to be called one after the other - figured a single function i can pass functions into would make it more streamlined. Thanks -

Answer (score 1):

Say you have some function, `double`, that takes an argument, `x`, and a callback, `k`

```js
const double = (x, k) =>
  k(x * 2)
  
double(2, console.log) // 4
double(3, console.log) // 6
```

Now say we want to run it 3 times in a row

```js
const double = (x, k) =>
  k(x * 2)
      
const tripleDouble = (x, k) =>
  double(x, y =>
    double(y, z =>
      double(z, k)))
      
tripleDouble(2, console.log) // 16
tripleDouble(3, console.log) // 24
```

But of course we had to statically code each continuation (`y => ...`, and `z => ...`). How would we make this work with a *variable amount* (array) of functions?

```js
const double = (x, k) =>
  k(x * 2)
  
const composek = (...fs) => (x, k) =>
  fs.reduce((acc, f) =>
    k => acc(x => f(x, k)), k => k(x)) (k)
  
const foo = composek(double, double, double)

foo(2, console.log) // 16
foo(3, console.log) // 24
```

This is ripe for some abstraction tho, and introduces my favourite monad, the Continuation Monad.

```js
const Cont = f => ({
  runCont: f,
  chain: g =>
    Cont(k => f(x => g(x).runCont(k)))
})

Cont.of = x => Cont(k => k(x))

const composek = (...fs) => (x, k) =>
  fs.reduce((acc,f) =>
    acc.chain(x =>
      Cont(k => f(x,k))), Cont.of(x)).runCont(k)
      
const double = (x, k) =>
  k(x * 2)
  
const foo = composek(double, double, double)

foo(2, console.log) // 16
foo(3, console.log) // 24
```

If you have freedom to change the functions you're chaining, this cleans up a little bit more – here, `double` has 1 parameter and returns a `Cont` instead of taking a callback as a second argument

```js
const Cont = f => ({
  runCont: f,
  chain: g =>
    Cont(k => f(x => g(x).runCont(k)))
})

Cont.of = x => Cont(k => k(x))

// simplified
const composek = (...fs) => (x, k) =>
  fs.reduce((acc,f) => acc.chain(f), Cont.of(x)).runCont(k)

// simplified
const double = x =>
  Cont.of(x * 2)
  
const foo = composek(double, double, double)

foo(2, console.log) // 16
foo(3, console.log) // 24
```

Of course if `double` was actually asynchronous, it would work the same

```
// change double to be async; output stays the same
const double = x =>
  Cont(k => setTimeout(k, 1000, x * 2))

const foo = composek(double, double, double)

foo(2, console.log) // 16
foo(3, console.log) // 24
```

Comment: This takes care of your problem of threading data through the functions too. Before you just had `a(), b(), c()`, but with this setup, `a` can pass data to `b` and so on. This is one of my favourite topics of programming, but I have to get going for a class. I'll be back later tonight if you have other questions ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? *(See comments, but fairly self-explanatory.)*

```
function functionChain() {
    var args = arguments;

    // MAKE SURE WE HAVE AT LEAST 1 PARAMETER
    if ( args.length < 1 ) { return; }

    // Start the process
    var i = -1;
    go();

    function go() {
        // Pre-increment so we start at 0
        ++i;
        if (i < args.length) {
            // We have a next function, do it and continue when we get the callback
            args[i](go);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```js
function functionChain() {
    var args = arguments;
    
    // MAKE SURE WE HAVE AT LEAST 1 PARAMETER
    if ( args.length < 1 ) { return; }

    // Start the process
    var i = -1;
    go();

    function go() {
        // Pre-increment so we start at 0
        ++i;
        if (i < args.length) {
            // We have a next function, do it and continue when we get the callback
            args[i](go);
        }
    }
}

// Just some functions for an example:
function a(callback) {
  console.log("a");
  callback();
}

function b(callback) {
  console.log("b");
  callback();
}

// Note this one is async
function c(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("c");
    callback();
  }, 100);
}

function d(callback) {
  console.log("d");
  callback();
}

functionChain(a, b, c, d);
```

---

That said, one of the reasons for promises is to allow composing possibly-async functions. If your functions returned promises, we'd use the `reduce` idiom:

```
function functionChain() {
    // Assumes the functions return promises (or at least thenables)
    Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(p, f) {
      return p.then(f);
    }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

```js
function functionChain() {
    Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(p, f) {
      return p.then(f);
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

// Just some functions for an example:
function a(callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.log("a");
    resolve();
  });
}

function b(callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.log("b");
    resolve();
  });
}

// Note this one has a delay
function c(callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("c");
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  });
}

function d(callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    console.log("d");
    resolve();
  });
}

functionChain(a, b, c, d);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs):

1. Wrap all slow functions with callbacks into nsynjs-aware wrappers (see wait()),
2. Put your logic into function as if it was synchronous (see synchronousCode()),
3. Run that function via nsynjs engine (see nsynjs.run())

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amaksr/nsynjs/master/nsynjs.js"></script>
<script>
  var wait = function (ctx, ms) {
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('firing timeout');
    ctx.resume();
   }, ms);
  };
  wait.nsynjsHasCallback = true;

  function synchronousCode() {
   function function1() { 
    console.log('in function1');
    wait(nsynjsCtx,1000);
   };

   function function2() { 
    console.log('in function2');
    wait(nsynjsCtx,1000);
   };

   function function3() { 
    console.log('in function3');
    wait(nsynjsCtx,1000);
   };
   
   
   function functionChain() {
      // MAKE SURE WE HAVE AT LEAST 1 PARAMETER
      if ( arguments.length < 1 ) return;

      for ( var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
     //console.log(i,arguments[i]);
     if ( typeof arguments[i] === 'function' ) {    
      arguments[i]();
     };
      };
   };
   
   functionChain(function1,function2,function3);
  }
  
  nsynjs.run(synchronousCode,{},function(){
   console.log("Synchronous Code done");
  })
 </script>
```

See https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples for more examples.